# How to make python continually save file io

Tags: python, file, io, stream

I have the following code,

```
def main():



    SucessCount = 0
    line = []
    StringList = ''


    url = "https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?key=&match_id=1957663499"
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()

    for i in range(1860878309, 1860878309 + 99999999999999999 ):
        with open("DotaResults.txt", "w") as file:
            if SucessCount > 70000:
                break
            result = http.request('GET', 'https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?key=F878695BB3657028B92BCA60CEA03E16&match_id=' + str(i))
            x = json.loads(result.data.decode('utf-8'))



            if('error' in x['result']):
                print("Not found")
            else:
                if validityCheck(x['result']['players']) == True and x['result']['game_mode'] == 22:

                    line = vectorList(x)
                    #print(line.count(1))
                    if(line.count(1) == 10 or line.count(1) == 11):
                        SucessCount += 1
                        print('Ok = ' + str(SucessCount))
                        print("MatchId = " + str(x['result']['match_id']))
                        StringList = ','.join([str(i) for i in line])
                        file.write(StringList + '\n')

                        if(SucessCount % 5 == 0):

                            file.flush()
                            file.close()
                            time.sleep(30)
```

The problem I am having is that when I press the stop button in pycharm(in normal running mode)nothing shows up in the file, even tho I am closing the file every time I loop. Does anybody know why or what i can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make four changes:

- Open the file before entering the `for` loop -- that is, swap the `with` statement and the `for` statement.
- Open the file in "a" mode instead of "w" mode.  "a" stands for "append".  Right now, every time you reopen the file it erases everything you wrote to it before.
- Call `file.flush()` immediately after `file.write()` (that is, before the `if SucessCount % 5 == 0`.)
- *Don't* close the file before sleeping.

Incidentally, the word "success" is spelled with two Cs, and in Python you do not have to put parentheses around the controlling expression of an `if` statement.